# Why does my WPF Datagrid button click method change more row backgrounds than I want?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        row.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
```

In the final grid, many rows change background color. Like it's changing the color for every first row on each page.

Why is that?

Comment: It's doing that because of virtualization. The `DataGridRow` objects are reused in multiple places. For that reason you should never mess with them the way you are doing. The WPF-correct way is like this: Your datagrid rows are displaying some kind of data item class. That class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and for your case it needs to have a property -- `HasBeenClicked` or some such. You then write a `Style` for `DataGridRow` that uses a `Trigger` to change the background red for a row where `HasBeenClicked` is true.

Comment: Yeah after googling a bit more, I am coming to that conculsion.

Comment: I [ran into this exact issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571832/silverlight-datagrid-block-selection) in my first experience with XAML, five years ago. It turns out that the styling stuff has a painful learning curve, but it's incredibly powerful once you get it nailed down.

Comment: [Here's some more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778944/wpf-datagrid-change-background-color-of-the-row-for-which-the-button-is-clicked)